# What does "=>" mean in javascript when used with export default?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am analyzing some angular js source code of `angular-file-upload` plugin and I have some problems trying to understand some code.

I know that `export` is part of the new ES6 standards and it used to export functions and objects from a given file (or module).

But the following syntax is a bit weird me :

```
let {
    copy,
    extend,
    forEach,
    isObject,
    isNumber,
    isDefined,
    isArray,
    element
    } = angular;


    export default (fileUploaderOptions, $rootScope, $http, $window, 
                      FileLikeObject, FileItem) => {


        let {
            File,
            FormData
            } = $window;


        class FileUploader { 

          // class implemention.... 
        }

        return FileUploader;
    }
```

What is the use of the `=>` operator in this statement?

Comment: I couldn't figure out the operator name actually, I tried some research...

Comment: Well, it's not an operator, is just part of the syntax...

Comment: Yeah got that.. thanks for your help anyway..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an [*arrow* function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (or *fat arrow* function):

```
(a, b, c) => { /* ... */ }
```

Is (almost) equivalent to:

```
function(a, b, c) { /* ... */ }
```

The only difference between arrow functions and functions declared with `function` is that `this` has lexical binding in arrow functions instead of the confused morass of binding in regular functions.

Comment: There is another thing it does. If you do `(a, b, c) => a + b + c` it's equivalent to `function (a, b, c) { return a + b + c; }`. When not using braces, if it has only one command, the result of it is returned.

Comment: Also, there's no "free" `arguments` variable pointing to an object of arguments.

Comment: Good point, Buzinas!  It seems so obvious to me that I forgot to point it out. Will update my answer

Comment: Thank you guys.. this is really useful..

Comment: Also true, squint: I consider that less interesting, though, because the spread operator is making the `arguments` operator redundant. But as far as I know, you're correct.

Comment: Confused morass? Well, now it's even more "confusing" as you need to take the call of your parent function (which still has its `this` with usual rules) into account.

Comment: I think consistency is less confusing; for arrow functions `this` follows the same scoping rules as variables. Also, the behavior of binding to the global scope of called from within a function UNLESS I'm strict mode, in which case it is null...madness.  You could argue it introduces an inconsistency because arrow functions behave differently than `function` functions, and that argument carries some weight....

Answer (score 1):

Its an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). In your case, it accounts to something like:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var _angular = angular;
var copy = _angular.copy;
var extend = _angular.extend;
var forEach = _angular.forEach;
var isObject = _angular.isObject;
var isNumber = _angular.isNumber;
var isDefined = _angular.isDefined;
var isArray = _angular.isArray;
var element = _angular.element;

exports["default"] = function (fileUploaderOptions, $rootScope, $http, $window, FileLikeObject, FileItem) {
    var File = $window.File;
    var FormData = $window.FormData;

    var FileUploader = function FileUploader() {
        _classCallCheck(this, FileUploader);
    };

    // class implemention....

    return FileUploader;
};

module.exports = exports["default"];
```

Note that this was compiled by [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).